# Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46. Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello i have a set of 431 PNG images that i want to create a movie and an MP3 Audio that i want to merge .
I have checked the photos and they all look ok .

### But when i try to fix the audio i get this error .

I execute this :
ffmpeg -y -i c:\mami\frame%1d.png -i c:\video\xema.mp3 -r 24.031924  -vframes 431 -codec:v libx264  colorized_mami.mp4

### PNG FILES ARE CORRECT NOT DAMAGED I CHECKED THEM

Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb8f25040] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d68c0] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d91c0] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d8400] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d9640] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d7680] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb8f20fc0] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb8f21fc0] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb8f23800] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb8f25040] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d68c0] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d91c0] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d8400] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d9640] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb91d7680] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[png @ 000001dfb8f20fc0] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input

```
Last message repeated 1 times
```

[png @ 000001dfb91d9640] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
    Last message repeated 6 times
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!

--
here is the link with the frames full
[link] (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e0be2o7448yr9r9/AAB1GmzmfMQjUeWeguZBfO7pa?dl=0)

Comment: Provide a link to one of these PNG files.

Comment: Hey,I am facing same issue.I didn't find any solution till.Did you found any solution? If find please share.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

because it is not png image, it is jpg image. replace .png with .jpg